# How do I setup a mock that returns IHttpActionResult?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, asp.net-web-api2, moq

I'm using VisualStudio 2015, .NET 4.6, Moq 4.5.2, Nunit 3.4.1 to test a WebApi2 Controller. However, I am getting a `null` response object when mocking the intended controller method:

> var response = actionResult as NegotiatedContentResult;

I am guessing I must be setting up my mock of the `UserService` incorrectly?

My suspicion is that this part is the culprit:

> userServiceMock.Setup(service => service.InsertOrUpdateUser(
>                   It.IsAny())).**Returns(1);**

As I am getting the following in the output window:

> '((System.Web.Http.Results.OkNegotiatedContentResult)actionResult).Request'
>   threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'

Is the problem that I am telling Moq to expect a return value of 1, but the Put method returns `OkNegotiatedContentResult`?

My questions are (possibly the same question):

1) Am I setting up my Moq correctly and

2) how do I resolve the problem so my response object is populated?

Thanks much.

Here is the Test method:

```
[Test]
public void Put_ShouldUpdate_User()
{
    // Arrange
    var userServiceMock = new Mock<IUserService>();

    userServiceMock.Setup(service => service.InsertOrUpdateUser(
        It.IsAny<User>())).Returns(1);

    var controller = new UsersController(userServiceMock.Object);

    // Act
    IHttpActionResult actionResult = controller.Put(

        new User()
        {
            Id = 1,
            Name = "Joe"
        });

    var response = actionResult as NegotiatedContentResult<User>;

    // Assert:
    Assert.IsNotNull(response);
    var newUser = response.Content;
    Assert.AreEqual(1, newUser.Id);
    Assert.AreEqual("Joe", newUser.Name);
}
```

Here is the `UserController` method:

```
// PUT api/users/1
public IHttpActionResult Put(User user)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    return Ok(_userService.InsertOrUpdateUser(user));

}
```

Finally, the method for the UserService:

```
public int InsertOrUpdateUser(User user)
{
    return _userRepository.InsertOrUpdateUser(user);
}
```

Comment: seems like the mock setup should be ok - the configured behavior should return an int like the method does.  I did notice that your exception shows a cast to the OkNegotiatedContentResult<T> type, but your code attempts to access it as a NegotiatedContentResult<T> -  these don't share a common base class, could that be the cause?

Comment: Thanks Andrew. Yes, I caught that earlier and tried changing NegotiatedContentResult to OKNegotiatedContentResult but it didn't seem to matter so I just left it.

Comment: which line is the exception thrown on?

Comment: Sorry, had to step through the code again. It is on this line: IHttpActionResult actionResult = controller.Put( etc... It seems to be generated in the UserControllers Put method.

Comment: Specifically, it looks like the error is being thrown inside UserController here: Ok(_tribeService.InsertOrUpdateTribe(tribe)); It seems to be thrown there. This is my call to my repository which I understand I do not need to be mocking in this test as Moq knows nothing about the Repository, it is just testing the Controller and the mocked Object I am passing to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your code `IUserService` has

```
public interface IUserService {

    int InsertOrUpdateUser(User user);

}
```

which returns an `int`.

If you do the following in your controller

```
return Ok(_userService.InsertOrUpdateUser(user));
```

then based on the interface and your setup mock, that will return  a response type of `OkNegotiatedContentResult<int>`. But in your test you do this

```
var response = actionResult as NegotiatedContentResult<User>;
```

where you cast your returned result as `NegotiatedContentResult<User>` this will cause `Assert.IsNotNull(response);` to fail as the cast will result in `response` being `null`.

Given the asserts of your test then you would have to update your controller's `Put` method to return the `User user` after the mocked action like so...

```
public IHttpActionResult Put(User user) {
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }
    var count = _userService.InsertOrUpdateUser(user);
    if(count == 1)
        return Ok(user);
    else
        return BadRequest(); // 500 (Internal Server Error) you choose. 
}
```

and also update the test as follows

```
//...other code removed for brevity

var response = actionResult as OkNegotiatedContentResult<User>;

// Assert:
Assert.IsNotNull(response);
var newUser = response.Content;
Assert.AreEqual(1, newUser.Id);
Assert.AreEqual("Joe", newUser.Name);
```

Comment: Thanks Nkosi, that was it. Silly oversight on my part. I don't want to change the controller so I have changed the test - essentially testing the correct int is returned in my Assert. Thanks again for the clarity.